# tfs build definition with no drop folder

Tags: tfs, build-automation

I've recently changed a number of my builds to not have a drop folder but now I'm getting the following error when I do this:

`The drop location for this build was empty. The build definition 'My Nightly Build' (or the build request) must specify a valid UNC path as the drop location for the build. Update the build definition and try again.`

This is how I changed it:

[image]

#### Error:

[image]

Can I not use this configuration or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This feature is a fairly new feature.  I would imagine that you have upgraded TFS, but not upgraded one of the build agents or maybe even visual studio.  Where are you getting the error exactly?

Comment: @gregpakes I'm getting it in the build log window.  I've attached a screenshot in the question.

Comment: @gregpakes Everything is 2010 (visual studio and tfs).

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to me that your build controller does not support not having a drop location.  Have you ensured that all appropriate updates are installed on the build controller that have already been installed on TFS directly?

Comment: I am thinking now that this is not supported in TFS 2010.  This is taken from the MSDN documentation for TFS 2010.  `The This build copies output files to a drop folder check box should remain selected. Your builds will fail if you clear this check box and use a build template that produces output.` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716(v=vs.100).aspx)  If you go into the 2012 documentation it describes the option to omit a drop location.  I don't know - but i don't think its supported.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your Build Process Template is based on the DefaultTemplate in TFS 2010, 
Got to:

1. Edit Build Definition...
2. Click Process on the left
3. Expand **Advanced**
4. Set `Copy Outputs to Drop Folder` = False

Then it should not require the Drop folder to be defined.